# Java NIO socket IO degenerating read chunk size

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I'm writing a non-blocking client that reads data from a network socket using selector `SelectionKey.OP_READ` and `selector.select()` calls. The reading part is handled like this:

```
if (selectionKey.isReadable()) {
    int len = inChannel.read(buf);
    System.out.println(len);
    . . .
}
```

The problem I see is that the read size (`len`) is gradually degenerating as the download progresses:

```
1290
1290
1290
480
318
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
```

Does anyone know why this is and how to improve it? Of course, it works as-is, but I need to reduce cpu overhead, and thus it is best to process large chunks instead of small ones. Adding a small sleep (20ms) helps, but will obviously limit scalability, as I need to handle thousands of streams  simultaneously.

Comment: I think you should reconsider what you are trying to do. A non-blocking read means "give me the data you have right now, and return ASAP". A non-blocking read which waited to get more data would actually be a blocking read, wouldn't it? What should the process do while it's waiting for data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question...

**Never mind**; I wasn't using the buffer correctly. Forgot the `compact()` call after reading from buffer.

```
if (selectionKey.isReadable()) {
    int len = inChannel.read(buf);
    System.out.println(len);
    . . .
    buf.flip();
    // ... read from buf ...
    buf.compact();
}
```

Apparently the buffers are not circular; even though a buffer is empty, the position and limit must be reset before next use.

Comment: You must `flip()` the buffer before getting anything out of it, and `compact()` it afterwards.